# Can a wizard's level-up spells choices be from outside their school?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, character-advancement

Does a wizard have to choose spells from their school? I understand scrolls or other methods could come in to play to learn specific spells through interaction with the world. But what are the requirements for new spells learned from gaining a level?

For instance I've just advanced to level six and I am an evocation wizard choosing two new spells. Can I choose from any spell from the wizard spell book or must it be an evocation spell?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it sounds like previous editions were much less ambiguous.

Comment: @Philipp Actually only 3.5rd edition allowed you to pick two prohibited schools. In 2nd edition and 3rd edition, each specialised school included a list of 1-3 other schools it forbade; In editions earlier than second, the eight schools hadn't yet been introduced.

Comment: Historical Note: Back in second edition, wizards only learned spells as part of gaining a level *if* they were specialised in a particular school, and the spells had to be from that school. The requirements for learning a new spell on level up changed drastically in subsequent editions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Yes, you can copy and learn spells from other schools.

From PHB 114.

> ***Copying a Spell into the Book.*** When you find a wizard spell of 1st
> level or higher, you can add it to your spellbook if it is of a level
> for which you have spell slots and if you can spare the time to
> decipher and copy it.

And

> ***Learning Spells of 1st Level and Higher.*** Each time you gain a wizard
> level, you can add two wizard spells o f your choice to your
> spellbook. Each of these spells must be of a level for which you have
> spell slots, as shown on the Wizard table.

As stated (or lack of), there is no limitation about schools in this edition.

Answer (score 6):

There are no restrictions on the spells you can select except it must be from the wizard list and must be a spell level that you can cast.