# Has Anyone Created a SpellBook for Their Character to Use as a Prop?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment

One of my players wanted a 'quick' (aka easy to make) spellbook as a prop for their character I was going to recommend using a leather bound journal and printing the actual spells from their class (the tome of wizarding spells) separate by levels and using the Stormning or AngloSaxon Runes font (for a dwarven looking spellbook) or using Tengwar Annatar/cursive (for a elven looking spellbook), my favorite is Arabic as I think it looks really cool - but unless you can read arabic it won't be functional.

Also I was thinking about recommending they only make the actual name of the spell in a special font so they can still read all the descriptive text; the benefit of this is that the player can actually reference their prop to prepare their spells and ascertain the damage/range/effect/etc..thoughts/experiences?

Comment: Hi Todd, I've closed this since this appears to be a discussion starter. On RPG Stack Exchange we focus on Q&A based around practical problems people are experiencing which are capable of receiving a single best/correct answer. We're not a discussion forum and don't handle open-ended discussions. However, you can instead ask about this on a forum -- [we've collected a list of forums we'd recommend here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449). The *Giant in the Playground* forums or the D&D 5e subreddit may be what you're looking for, for example.

Comment: Related and now possible dupe on Can a Wizard's level-up spell choices be from outside their school](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87218/can-a-wizards-level-up-spells-choices-be-from-outside-their-school)

Comment: Your edit seems to have changed the question significantly from what you asked originally. Thus I have rolled back your edits to the original (you can access the old text [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/122846/revisions)). In this case, it is better to ask a new question since it is so different. However, you might want to check this question first to see if it gives you an answer because it looks like your new question may be a duplicate of it: [Can a wizard's level-up spells choices be from outside their school?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87218)